# Is there any easy way to know which, if any, of my Delicious links are broken?

Tags: links, delicious

I have a number of links going back several years.  I'd like to prune out or repair, if possible, the broken links, that is, the ones whose address has changed or no longer exists.

Is there any easy way to tell which links are broken in Delicious so that I don't have to examine them one by one?

Comment: are the links public?

Comment: @neo - yes, I think they are all public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tools available for download:

- [Fresh Delicious](http://sites.google.com/site/freshdelicious/home) which works an all Java-enabled platforms
- [deadlicious](http://www.malarkeysoftware.com/projects_dead-licious.html) for Mac OS X only
- [Delicious Link checker](http://www.unixdaemon.net/delicious-checker.html), a perl script

Those aren't online based but out of the last one it would be easy to build a web app ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, what happens with most dead links these days is that they end up pointing to domain squatters rather than actual dead links which return an error when you try to get them.

Comment: That of course is a problem. At least the perl script should be quite easily tweakable to detect this.

Comment: How can you detect a domain squatter with a script?

Comment: @Kinopiko: You could probably detect known squatters based on some distinguishing characteristic of their pages. I'm not sure how reliable it would be though, and maintenance could be a nightmare.

Comment: We can detect pictures of a girl with a rucksack.